# How to use file in html5 filesystem api with SoundManager 2

Tags: javascript, html, soundmanager2, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to write mp3s using the HTML5 Filesystem API in the user's local filesystem using PERMANENT STORAGE. I have a drag and drop region where an event triggers dataTransfer.files. But how do I load the file with SoundManager 2 to play the mp3 in browser?

Soundmanager requires a path as an argument to createSound:

```
  url: [
    {type:'audio/mp3',url:'/path/to/play.php?song=123'}
  ]
```

What is the path to the file I've successfully read using the Filesystem API?

The following successfully runs:

```
var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

// files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
//var output = [];
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  audio.playlist.push(escape(f.name));  // saving filenames in array for playlist
  writeFile(fs.root,files[i]);

}
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
 fs.root.getFile(escape(files[i].name), {create: false}, function(fileEntry) {
       alert('A file ' + fileEntry.name + ' was read successfully.');
}, errorHandler);


}
```

Later I call Soundmanager 2 (which only works when I pass relative file paths to it) -

```
    audio.nowPlaying = soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'aSound',
        url: audio.playlist[playlistId],
        autoLoad: true,
        volume: 20,

        // ...with a recursive callback when play completes
        onfinish: function(){
            playlistId ++;
            playAudio(playlistId);
        }
    })
```

Comment: If I understand your approach right, you're having users drag-n-drop MP3 files on to the browser, which it then stores (or re-stores) the MP3s as local storage, which you then want to retrieve and give to the Sound Manager. The File System API has a `.toUrl()` method that generates virtual URLs that you can feed to SRC or HREF attributes; it'll likely work for Sound Manager as well. Have you tried sending a "filesystem://" URL to the Sound Manager?  For a demo see: [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: I ended up using dancer.js for my project instead of SoundManager. I couldn't get Soundmanager 2 to accept the file path for mp3s located in the HTML5 filesystem API. Dancer.js doesn't rely on flash for the audio waveform data either, native HTML5 instead. Check out what I made at http://kineticvideo.co